# crossplane automation tools for resource lifecycle operations

Tags: kubernetes, automation, cloud, build-automation, crossplane

We are looking for an open-source tool that we can use to create/update/delete cloud resources using cross-plane. we should use cross-plane managed resources to poll services status and complete the automation lifecycle.

we can achieve this by writing some shell scripts too but wondering if any such tool is available.

please share the info if you know something related to the same. it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one repo for same but they are having less document or tutorials as of now

https://github.com/upbound/uptest/

The end to end integration testing tool for Crossplane providers and configurations.

Uptest comes as a binary which can be installed from the releases section. It runs end-to-end tests by applying the provided examples and waiting for the expected conditions. Other than that, it enables templating to insert dynamic values into the examples and supports running scripts as hooks just before and right after applying the examples.